# How to resize image in timelineitem

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I set an image in timelineitem. 
Now I want to **resize** the image and set **alignment** of the image.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put an  tag in the html property of a timeline card, you can set the style attribute on it to size/format it with normal CSS